# WPF DataGrid cannot add a row when DataSource is empty

Tags: wpf, datagrid

`CanUserAddRows="True"` only works when there's already data in the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`. If there are no rows in the original items list, then the `DataGrid` doesn't display a placeholder row for entering new items, even though I've set `CanUserAddRows="True"`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: also what happens is you cant scroll right to see columns that are off the screen, cause you have no horizontal scrollbars with no items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seem to be a known issue with WPF DataGrid. See discussion [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/05/27/using-ieditablecollectionview-with-dynamically-generated-gridviewcolumns.aspx) (starting from the 4th comment) Also it seem to be fixed in .net 4. I've made some tests for this issue on 3.5 and 4 (beta2) frameworks. Pls, see results below:

First I defined 3 types of item collections:

```
public class TestGridItems0 : ArrayList
{
}

public class TestGridItems1 : List<TestGridItem>
{
}

public class TestGridItems2<T> : List<TestGridItem>
{
}
```

where TestGridItem is below:

```
public class TestGridItem
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
    public string Three { get; set; }
}
```

**.net 3.5**

TestGridItems0 and TestGridItems1 didn't show an empty line for an empty collection; where as TestGridItems2 did work fine.

**.net 4**

only TestGridItems0 didn't show the line for the empty collection; other 2 worked fine.

xaml for the grid:

```
<my:DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True">
    <my:DataGrid.Columns>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding One}" Header="One" />
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Two}" Header="Two" />
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Three}" Header="Three" />
    </my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

below is how items source was assigned:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new TestGridItems0();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new TestGridItems1();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new TestGridItems2<TestGridItem>();
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: A simple `.ToList()` conversion solved the problem. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty item to your ItemsSource and then remove it. You may have to set CanUserAddRows back to true after doing this. I read this solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/cdc0fb6f-2335-42e2-98d7-4bd73ffffc8c): (Posts by Jarrey and Rick Roen)

I had this problem when I set the ItemsSource to a DataTable's DefaultView and the view was empty. The columns were defined though so it should have been able to get them. Heh.