# Binding to datagrid in ActivityDesigner

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, workflow-foundation-4, activitydesigner

I am new to .NET 4 and I am looking for a way to design a custom activity that accepts a list of some type (in my example `FormInput`). So, each instance of this activity can hold its own private list of FormInput.

This codesnippet is from the activity designer what I have trying to, which for some reason, doesn't work. The datagrid is disabled when using my activity in a workflow.

```
<Grid>...
   <DataGrid AutomationProperties.AutomationId="InputElements" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelItem.InputElements}" CanUserAddRows="True"
      CanUserDeleteRows="True"></DataGrid>
...
</Grid>
```

And this is the property of the custom Activity class that should hold the list.

```
public ObservableCollection<FormInput> InputElements
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you initialize your ObservableCollection<FormInput> to non-null?

Comment: Disabled or does not have data?

Comment: Even initializing ObservableCollection<FormInput> to non-null, it appears Disabled

Answer (score 1):

I got it, think the problem was the binding to a non enumerable object.

Binding directly to the `ModelItem` property value resolved the issue

```
public partial class ActivityDesigner1
{
    public ObservableCollection<FormInput> MyProperty
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<FormInput>)ModelItem.Properties["InputElements"].ComputedValue; }
    }
}
```

And in designer: `<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyProperty}"...`

You shoud be able to do it using a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075644/wpf-datagrid-cannot-add-a-row-when-datasource-is-empty) to solve the problem of adding the first item

Oh, don't forget to initialize your ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0):

Check if `DataContext` of `DataGrid` is set correctly and use code snippet for collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<FormInput> inputElements;

public ObservableCollection<FormInput> InputElements
{
    get
    {
        if (this.inputElements == null)
        {
            this.inputElements = new ObservableCollection<FormInput>();
        }

        return this.inputElements;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, you must remember that this thread is not just about WPF, but WPF with WF4