# Unable to add new Row in DataGrid UI automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm unable to add new rows in my `DataGrid` from UI. Below is my code.

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" Name="dg"  ItemsSource="{Binding list}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Header="Text"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Length}" Header="Length"/>            
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

> ***`list`*** is a list of string in above `Binding`.Usually when I set `CanUserAddRows="True"` I was able to add rows on UI automatically in other examples.

My property is as following:

```
public List<string> list { get; set; }
```

And before display of `DataGrid` it has been initialized. So no need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this property.

Can someone explain me why the `DataGrid` is behaving this way? How to achieve desired behavior?

Comment: As far I know when you bind a DataGrid you can't add rows manually

Comment: @Rodolfo sure you can.

Comment: @Rodolfo that example is for DataGridView. not  applicable here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075644/wpf-datagrid-cannot-add-a-row-when-datasource-is-empty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480098/how-do-i-create-a-new-row-in-wpf-datagrid-when-it-is-bound-to-an-xmldataprovider

Comment: @Rodolfo my ItemSource is not empty so first link is not relative

Comment: Also I've not bound the grid to any XML data provider

Comment: Read the solutions, read about the default constructor of a bound class

Comment: @Rodolfo not my case. the solution is all about empty collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `string` does not have a parameter-less constructor, so the grid can't create a new instance for the empty grid row that allows the user to add a new row.  Further, the grid can't "set" the "." property onto the string.

One option is to create your own class that exposes Text and Length properties:

```
public class StringMember : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string m_actualString;
public string Text
{
    get { return m_actualString; }
    set
    {
        m_actualString = value;
        //OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        //OnPropertyChanged("Length");
    }
}

public int Length { get { return Value.Length; } }

//public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
//protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
//{
//    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
//    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
//}
```

}

Then, your XAML would bind to your properties:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" Name="dg"  ItemsSource="{Binding list}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text}" Header="Text"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Length}" Header="Length"/>            
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In this case, your "list" property would be `List<StringMember>` or `ObservableCollection<StringMember>` instead of `string`.

Comment: so how to deal with the situation where my model classes don't have default constructor def.? will a optional parameter will do?

Comment: so do you know any work around of this then in which I don't have to create derived/wrapper classes?